# identityServer 3 message error connecting client: "Unknown client or not enabled"

Tags: openid, identityserver3, thinktecture

When i try to connect my client with identityServer, server log show next message:

- [Error] "Unknown client or not enabled: cliente1"*

this is my **OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions**:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "cliente1",
            Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57598/",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            Scope = "openid email",

            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        });
    }
```

and this is my **identityServer client configuration**:

```
               new Client{

                ClientName = "cliente1",
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "cliente1",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },


                Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                //RequireConsent = true,
                //AllowRememberConsent = true,

                RedirectUris = new List<string> {
                    "http://localhost:57598/"
                },

                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>{
                    "http://localhost:57598/"
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    //Constants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    //"read",
                    //"write",
                    "webapi"
                },

                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,

                IdentityTokenLifetime = 360,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 360
            },
```

What could be the problem?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Enable logging first: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html

Comment: logging is enable in my server and file log show next message:

[Error] "Unknown client or not enabled: cliente1"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using MS's OpenID Connect middleware in your ASP.NET MVC application, which works with the Hybrid flow, but the Client's flow is set to Implicit.  Set the flow to Hybrid (Flow = Flows.Hybrid), and it should work.